# Kryo Serialization Error in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, kryo

I want to register kryo Serialization, for that i have written below code,

First Class (Select.Class)

```
var SparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
      .set("spark.kryo.registrator", "org.agg.MyRegistrator")

var sc = new SparkContext(SparkConf)
var sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)


val testdata_select = sqlContext.sql("select a,b, from test")
```

Second Class (MyRegistrator.Class)

```
class MyRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {
  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
    kryo.register(classOf[TransformationCode])
  } 
}
```

Third Class (TransformationCode.Class)

```
//Transformation Code
```

But it gives me error that

> User class threw exception: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not
>   serializable`

Comment: How are you using `Select.Class` in your code? Show us the definition of your Spark graph.

Comment: you shouldn't register your transformation code, you should register you data classes. The classes that hold the data that need to be moved around during shuffle, collect, etc.